# `gpg --list-keys` does not list my keys

Tags: gnupg

I've added a lot of keys to my Ubuntu 20.04 computer and when I issue the `gpg --list-keys` command in my terminal I only get silent output (ie nothing is returned). `sudo gpg --list-keys` doesn't list any of my keys either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can try the 'passwords and keys' aka 'seahorse' gui to look at these. I can't verify that it works though, because I don't have any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a user uses `gpg` or `gpg2` to import public keys, the keys are stored in the public keyring that is in `~/.gnugpg` by default. If you used `apt-key` the public keys are stored in individual `.gpg` files in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`. The following command runs the `gpg` command without arguments for each gpg file in `/etc/apt` to cover cases where the name of the folder is different from the default. Gpg guesses what output you want based on the content of the file passed as argument:

```
find /etc/apt/ -name \*.gpg | xargs -n 1 gpg
```

The following alternative command sets each file as the keyring and ignores the default keyring, this way you can replace the `--list-public-keys` by `--export --armor` to export public keys to text format:

```
find /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ -type f | \
   xargs -n 1 gpg --no-default-keyring --list-public-keys --keyring
```

Comment: `gpg2 --list-keys` gave the error "_gpg2 no command found_". What is the file name in my home directory for these keys, and can I view this file in any text editor (eg gedit)?

Comment: Check `/home/user/.gnupg/` `~/.gnupg` how did you add the keys in the first place?

Comment: that directory is there but I can't read any of the files inside it in a regular text editor. I assume that's expected behavior. Keys I have added have been in this style `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10`

Comment: Those keys are system wide keys so they are not in a user folder, try `find /etc/apt/ -name \*.gpg | xargs -n 1 gpg` that should give you the output you were looking for. You will find files with `.gpg` extension in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` this are binary files that you can't edit with a text editor but you can convert them to ascii armor files if you want. When you pass a `.gpg` file to the gpg command it will detect the format and provide the right output. You can also pass the argument `--primary-keyring` pointing to the .gpg file with public keys inside for other operations.

Comment: it looks like `find /etc/apt/ -name \*.gpg | xargs -n 1 gpg` is the command I need. Can you modify the answer to put this command instead of what you've got? Also, when I run that command I get a warning, "_No command supplied. Trying to guess what you mean..._". Is the syntax slightly off?

Comment: any idea why `gpg --list-keys` doesn't display anything (silent output)? `find /etc/apt/ -name \*.gpg | xargs -n 1 gpg` does work as you describe, and shows all my keys.

Comment: Yes, because it uses the user's home keyring by default, `gpg --no-default-keyring --list-public-keys --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/file.gpg` changes the keyring file and tells gpg to ignore the default keyring, but I don't know the exact name of your files so I used the `find` command

Comment: and to close this all out when I issue a command such as `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10` why doesn't it place the keys in my `/home` keyring (the presumed default behavior)?

Comment: Because you are using the `apt-key` command that is a wrapper of `gpg` to download keys and put them in the system's configuration folder. `apt-key` is a shell script, you can edit it and see how it works.